# Unable to open popup window from django admin change view

Tags: python, django, popup, django-admin

I am trying to open a simple popup window from the Django admin change view,

**change_form.html**(overridden)

```
<li><a href="/admin/django_ipam/ipaddress/add/?_to_field=id&_popup=1&ip_address={{i}}&subnet={{subnet}}">{{i}}</a></li>
```

Instead of showing a popup, it navigates to that page(looks obvious though) and upon saving the form the page is stuck as `Popup closing...`. What is the correct way to do this?